# Can I bake building silhouettes into a skybox in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

Im working on a VR project where we want to recreate an existing place in Unity. Due to the overall setting of the game, the render distance cannot be set too high.

However, there are some faraway landmark buildings that we would like to include. I had the idea to bake the outlines / silhouettes of these buildings into the skybox. Is this possible? If so, what is the easiest way to do this?

I currently have a skybox material which is generated from 6 images, like a cubemap but with separate image files. I also have 3D models of the buildings which are placed correctly relative to the player.

Any tips are appreciated! :)